# Group or sort values in calc (libre office)

Tags: libreoffice, subtotal, libreoffice-calc

Sorry for non-programmatic question - I need a help with libre office tools.
I have (for example) such table, where the first column is an IP addresses

```
A       B      C  
2.3.4.5      bbb     22c
1.2.1.4      aaa     11v
4.2.3.5      ccc     33v
1.2.1.4      ddd     55c
```

And I need to group (or sort) them - to compare a data from the same IP, so the result must be something like this:

```
A       B      C  
1.2.1.4      aaa     11v
1.2.1.4      ddd     55c
2.3.4.5      bbb     22c
4.2.3.5      ccc     33v
```

how could it be done ?

Answer (score 1):

`Data` -> `Sort`

Then specify the keys (in your case, simply *Column A*, *Ascending*)

[image]

@see https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Sorting_Data